# How to implement the best OAuth authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, mern

I'm using zendesk OAuth for authorization. I'm using the MERN stack and the current implementation works like this,

1. User clicks login and redirected to zendesk
2. once the user signs I get redirected back to /callback path
3. Where I sent another request to get an auth token
4. After I get the token I redirect the user to frontend as `?token=XXXX` attached to the URL

Is this the correct way? How should I proceed with the token should I keep it in session storage? It's not a good idea to expose the token?

```
export const authCallback = (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
  const body = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: req.query.code,
    client_id: process.env.ZENDESK_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.ZENDESK_SECRET,
  }

  axios
    .post(`https://${process.env.SUBDOMAIN}.zendesk.com/oauth/tokens`, body, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const token = response.data.access_token
      return res.redirect(`${process.env.ORIGIN}?token=${token}`)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message })
    })
}
```

Comment: It is safer to keep the token in the session storage and send only the session cookie to the browser (with HttpOnly, so that the cookie cannot be accessed via Javascript).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen so in the FE once I got redirected with the token in the URL I should be storing it?

Comment: Sorry, no. I meant, use [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and store the token on the _server_ in `req.session.token`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and store the token on the *server* in `req.session.token`:

```js
(response) => {
  req.session.token = response.data.access_token;
  req.session.save(function() {
    res.redirect(`${process.env.ORIGIN}`)
  });
}
```

Or send the token in a session cookie directly:

```js
(response) => {
  res.cookie("token", response.data.access_token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None"
  });
  res.redirect(`${process.env.ORIGIN}`)
}
```

Comment: In the FE how do I know the user is logged in with this method?

Comment: Is the user contained in the access token?

Comment: No, I need to call the /me endpoint to get the user.

Comment: Then include the access token in the request to the `/me` endpoint. If you use server-side rending, you can include the user name in the HTML page that you generate.